# Returning the inverse matrix from a cached object in R checking that input matrix has not changed

Tags: caching, matrix, scoping, inverse, lexical

Disclosure: This is from a programming assignment from a Coursera Course called R programming. I originally had up the full code but took parts of it out since I realize I am not permitted to upload my full code (granted the code I uploaded didn't work).

The assignment is regarding lexical scoping and caching functions that may require a long computation time. Specifically I am using solve() to find the inverse of a matrix and cache it using a free floating variable. I am also trying to cache the input matrix so that I can retrieve it and compare it to any new input matrices. I am returning an error on the latter as described below.

First, I run both makeCacheMatrix and cacheSolve as per the code below.

The first function, makeCacheMatrix creates a special "matrix" object that can cache the input matrix and its inverse

```
makeCacheMatrix <- function(x = matrix()) {
m <- NULL # sets the value of m to NULL (provides a default if cacheSolve has not yet been used)
y <- NULL # sets the value of y to NULL (provides a default if cacheSolve has not yet been used)
setmatrix <- function(y) { #set the value of the matrix
    x <<- y ## caches the inputted matrix so that cacheSolve can check whether it has changed (note this is within the setmatrix function)
    m <<- NULL # # sets the value of m (the matrix inverse if used cacheSolve) to NULL
}
# Parts removed
list(setmatrix = setmatrix, getmatrix = getmatrix, # creates a list to house the four functions
   setinverse = setinverse,
   getinverse = getinverse)
}
```

The second function cacheSolve calls functions stored in the special "matrix" returned by makeCacheMatrix (above). If the inverse has already been calculated (and the matrix has not changed), then cacheSolve retrieves the inverse from the cache. If the input is new, it calculates the inverse of the data and sets the inverse in the cache via the setinverse function.

```
cacheSolve <- function (x=matrix(), ...) {
# Need to compare matrix to what was there before!
m <- x$getinverse() # if an inverse has already been calculated this gets it
if(!is.null(m)){ # check to see if cacheSolve has been run before
    if(x$setmatrix() == x$getmatrix()) { # check that matrix hasn't changed, and if it hasn't, sends a text message and returns the cached matrix
        #parts removed
    return(m)
    }
# otherwise 
y <- x$getmatrix() # run the getmatrix function to get the value of the input matrix
x$setmatrix(y) # run the setmatrix function on the input matrix to cache it
m <- solve(y, ...) # compute the value of the inverse of the input matrix
x$setinverse(m) # run the setinverse function on the inverse to cache the inverse
m # return the inverse
```

}

Then I test it using the following code:

```
mat <- matrix(data = c(4,2,7,6), nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
mat2 <- makeCacheMatrix(mat)
cacheSolve(mat2)
```

This gives the inverse as expected.

But when I try to test the cache capability by running the same matrix again.

```
cacheSolve(mat2)
```

It returns "Error in x$setmatrix() : argument "y" is missing, with no default. However, I thought I provided the default NULL in the second line of makeCacheMatrix.
I expected it to give the message "getting cached data" and then the inverse.

What am I doing wrong? How can I cache the input matrix using setmatrix and provide the default y?

Answer (score 0):

Try cacheSolve <- function (x, ...) and then only perform if(!is.null(m)) test. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! Yes this does work ... though I think that it doesn't check whether or not the input matrix has changed (only whether an inverse has been stored previously). I managed to get it working  by solving the input matrix and comparing to the cached inverse using "&& identical()"